# string '-1' can't be converted to float

Tags: python, string-conversion

I try to read large sets of numbers from a text file opened with utf-8 encoding.
The text file was a copy/paste from a pdf.
The problem lies in the negative numbers (-1, -2 etc):
I stripped everything, so the individual string bits look like this: `-1`, `-2` etc.

Then I want to calculate with them and convert them with `float()`, but I get an error:

```
can't convert string to float: '-1'
```

I concluded, the `'-'` could be interpreted as a long `'-'`, whatever that is called and replaced it manually in the text file by a `'-'`. Now it worked for this single string, float() converted it.
I wrote a small script that finds and replaces all `'-'` by `'-'` in the text file, but that didn't work.

```
with open('text.txt', encoding='utf8') as fobj:
    all = []
    for line in fobj:
        line = line.strip()
        if '-' in line:
            line.replace('-','-')
            print('replaced')
        all.append(line)
with open('text2.txt','w',encoding='utf8') as f:
    for i in all:
        print(i)
        f.write(i)
        f.write('\n')
```

Why is it I can replace `'-'` by `'-'` manually but not with this script?
Thanks for help.

Example snipped from the text file:

```
/ 11/3 / 2 / 0 / 0/–1 /
/ 11/5 / 0 / 2 / 0/0 / N
/ 12/3 / 1 / 0 / 0/0 /
/ 12/4 / 1 / 1 / 0/0 / NS

/ 12/4 / 4 / –1 / 0/–1 / H

/ 12/5 / 1 / 0 / 0/–1 / H

/ 12/5 / 2 / 0 / 0/-1 / H

/ 11/4 / 0 / 0 / 0/0 / H
```

You can actually see the difference between the second last and third last lines -1. In this copy that is. i replaced the last - manually.

Comment: `float(str(-1))` works. Are you sure it isn't `- 1` with a space in between?

Comment: Yes, I checked for that. several times. The problem is somehow with the -  Is there a way to replace them by ASCII code?

Comment: Can you copy few lines of the text file and add it to the question.

Comment: can you show us the format of the content in text.txt. in which part exactly do you apply the function float() ?

Comment: +1. I had some documentation for UNIX commands in a wiki because the doc-writer put replaced the normal keyboard hyphen (a "hyphen-minus") with a literal "em-dash". That meant that cutting and pasting the examples in the docs didn't work in real life. When I asked "why?", he said "it looked more readable, and implied the command was for typing and the docs should not used with "cut-and-paste".

Comment: You need to put `line = line.replace('-','-')`. you missed `line` assignment

Comment: @OsumanAAA: I read it in line by line then split by ' / ' so that only the numbers as strings are left over in large dictionarys. then when needed, I float(dict['x']['y']['z']) where there is the string '-1' located. hope that helps

Comment: @itzMEonTV: you are my hero!! It's always the simple/stupid errors. Thank you!

Comment: I am not sure it should be closed. While it is indeed because of two small mistakes that the code didn't do waht it was to, we learn two impoerant things here: 1. `replace` returns its replacement, which must be re-assigned (ok, that's trivial) and 2. there are several types of dashes which must be distinguished.

Answer (score 2):

You missed `line` assignment

```
if '-' in line:
    line = line.replace('-','-')
    print('replaced')
```

Comment: But `line = line.replace('-','-')` still won't do anything - both are the "usual" dashes.

Answer (score 1):

I just looked at your code: it does `replace('-','-')` – which is the same character.

You should either do `replace('–','-')`, or, for better clarity of what you do, `replace(u'\u2013', '-')`.

Besides, your re-assignment to `line` is missing.

Answer (score 1):

use both answers your code should be:

```
with open('text.txt', encoding='utf8') as fobj:
        all_ = []
        for line in fobj:
            line = line.strip()
            if u'\u2013' in line:
                line = line.replace(u'\u2013', '-')
                print('replaced', line)
            all_.append(line)
    with open('text2.txt','w',encoding='utf8') as f:
        for i in all_:
            print(i)
            f.write(i)
            f.write('\n')
```

result is

```
replaced / 11/3 / 2 / 0 / 0/-1 /
replaced / 12/4 / 4 / -1 / 0/-1 / H
replaced / 12/5 / 1 / 0 / 0/-1 / H
/ 11/3 / 2 / 0 / 0/-1 /
/ 11/5 / 0 / 2 / 0/0 / N
/ 12/3 / 1 / 0 / 0/0 /
/ 12/4 / 1 / 1 / 0/0 / NS

/ 12/4 / 4 / -1 / 0/-1 / H

/ 12/5 / 1 / 0 / 0/-1 / H

/ 12/5 / 2 / 0 / 0/-1 / H

/ 11/4 / 0 / 0 / 0/0 / H
```